# unusual initialization of variables c++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double a;
    double b;
    cin >> a,b;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "a= "<< a << " b=" << b;    
    return 0;
}
```

Why value of b is 1.4822e-323 in this case ?

Comment: that's because your code does not do what you think.  Have you stepped through it watching how the value of `b` changes?

Comment: Try to enter two float values separated by a return.

Comment: [*warning: expression result unused* with an arrow pointing to the `b` in `a,b`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db661679fa6b7c99). You should be asking about that, not the results of running it. If you don't get that warning, you need to get into the habit of compiling with more warnings.

Answer (score 4):

```
cin >> a,b;
```

uses the infamous [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which has the lowest [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in C++. Basically, the above statement is evaluated as:

```
(cin >> a) , b;
```

So, first `(cin >> a)` is being evaluated, with the effect that the input from `cin` is written to `a`, and an `istream` is returned. Then, the comma operator is invoked between the latter `istream` and `b`, which in effect discards the first operand, so the end result of the statement is `b`, which therefore remains uninitialized.

As mentioned in @IVlad's answer, the correct way of reading `a` and `b` is

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

Comment: Thanks for brightening guys, but I am still thinking about the "1.4822e-323" meaning. @IVlad said that value I get is  more or less random. But it isn't random. It's always the same in my case even when I make new project. What refer this value ? Is it range of double or reference to the address of cells ? I have no idea, have you any ? 
if I understood well cin >> a,b; equals cin >> a;b;  ??

Answer (score 3):

This happens because this line:

```
cin >> a, b;
```

Does not mean `read a and read b`. It is closer to this:

```
cin >> a;
b;
```

In order to read both values, you want to do `cin >> a >> b`. `b` being equal to the value you get is more or less random, since you do not initialize `b`, nor do you actually read it.